Probability between a rectangular 2D die and a squared 2D die
I'm trying to find a solution to the next problem:
If I have a rectangular $2D$-die with uniform density such that each side has a certain probability $P1,P2,P3,P4$ respectively.
I want to find a bijection between this die and a $2D$-square die with displaced center of mass.
I started by making a drawing, but I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Please clarify what you mean by a side having a certain probability: is it the probability of the side landing "face-up", or something else? I'm also not sure what you mean by bijection in this case, what is being mapped to what?

What I mean is that if we have a 2D rectangle with faces 1,2,3,4 with the probabilities of falling to the ground P1,P2,P3,P4 respectively. How could you create a bijection such that a 2D square has the same probabilities on each face but with the center of mass displaced?

What I want is to understand where the center of mass would be.

Understood. How are you modelling the dice? To be physically accurate you'd need to run actual physics simulations; do you have a formula for the probabilities of the faces of the square die, given the position of the baricenter, or is that part of the problem?

I think its related with angles

It's a bit confusing that you talk about a 2D die having "faces" and "falling to the ground". But if I've understood you correctly, the first thing to notice is that since the rectangular die is of uniform density, the probabilities occur in pairs (if the rectangle is $ABCD$, the probability of landing on side $AB$ is the same as that of landing on $CD$). Now think about how a square die with centre of mass away from its geometric centre would fall. These two ideas should tell you that the shifted centre of mass has to lie on a line of symmetry; so you have two distinct choices.

For physical modelling, you can imagine turning the lamina through an arbitrary angle, placing it on the ground, and seeing which way it would fall. (This ignores things like angular momentum, moments of inertia, different ways of "rolling" such a die, and toppling, but should give a good start.)
